# TokBox Subscriber Timeout Error

Tags: ios, video, nserror, tokbox, opentok

I am using TokBox for an app.  When doing P2P, one client shows both the local video and the other clients video.  The other client only shows the local video and calls `-subscriber:didFailWithError:` with the error `Error Domain=OTSubscriberErrorDomain Code=1 "The subscriber timed out."`  First, is there a way to change the TokBox timeout time.  Second, why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change the Timeout time. Second, I think you might have firewall settings that could be preventing streams from being subscribed. Heres a diagnostic tool to help you check your network: http://tokbox.com/tools/connectivity/